# How do I get a random beer every time I reload the page?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, api

I'm trying to fetch a random beer and a list of 20 beers from the Punk Beer API , and display it on the page. However, for some reason, the API with the random url kept returning the same beer (id:221, name: Blitz Series).I'm confused why it's not a different beer each time I reload the page. 
Here's my code :

```
componentDidMount(){
   const root_api = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/";
 var self = this;

   axios.all([
    axios.get(`${root_api}/beers/random`),
    axios.get(`${root_api}beers?page=2&per_page=20`)

  ])
  .then(axios.spread(function (randomBeerResponse, beerListResponse) {
    self.setState({randomBeer:randomBeerResponse.data[0]})
         self.setState({beers:beerListResponse.data})


  }));

}
```

Comment: Does the `/beers/random` action return a HTTP 3xx redirect instead of returning a `Beer` entity directly? If so, then your `axios` object's HTTP client is likely caching the redirect instead of making a brand new request.

Comment: How do I know whether or not the action returned a HTTP 3xx redirect? I'm not familiar with this concept. Please explain! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `const root_api = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/";` to `axios.get(`${root_api}/beers/random`)` which creates "https://api.punkapi.com/v2//beers/random"

As you can see there are two slashes `"//"` between `v2` and `beers` and that leads to returning the same beer over and over again.

Write `axios.get(`${root_api}beers/random`)` instead and the problem will resolve.

The whole code in correct format would be:

```
componentDidMount(){

     const root_api = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/";
     var self = this;

       axios.all([
        axios.get(`${root_api}beers/random`),
        axios.get(`${root_api}beers?page=2&per_page=20`)

      ])
      .then(axios.spread(function (randomBeerResponse, beerListResponse) {
        self.setState({randomBeer:randomBeerResponse.data[0]})
             self.setState({beers:beerListResponse.data})


      }));

    }
```

As a side-note, when you're dealing with API, you should test the API outside of your program with an API testing/development tool like Postman.

The problem here has nothing to do with React. It's just the API.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header in your axios request : `headers: {"Pragma", "no-cache"}`;

This tells browser to make a new call everytime and not memorize the previous request.